# Question about the proof of convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I am following the notes for my master's program, trying to prove conv.in probability implies conv. in distribution. The proof goes:

Let $F_n$ be the distribution function of $X$. Fix any $x$ s.t. $F$ is continuous at $x$, and fix any $\epsilon>0$. Observe that if $X_n \leq x$ then either $X\leq x+\epsilon$ or $|X_n-X|>\epsilon$.

Here I am confused about the observation. I tried drawing this and I feel like these two cases are not mutually exclusive. I understand the rest of the proof once I assume this part and I think I understand this part too. However, I think my problem is related to the use of "either ... or". When mathematicians use "or" do they use it like it is used in logic (where the statement is correct even when both predicates are correct) or daily use(which implies the two options are mutually exclusive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\{X_n\le x\}&=\{X_n\le x,|X-X_n|\le \epsilon\}\cup\{X_n\le x,|X-X_n|>\epsilon\} \\
&\subseteq \{X\le x+\epsilon\}\cup\{|X-X_n|>\epsilon\},
\end{align}
which means that if $\omega\in\{X_n\le x\}$, then $\omega$ belongs to at least one of the sets in the union on the RHS.

Comment: thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have this proof originally in English or you are translating it yourself for MSE?

I think in English, if you say just `A or B` then that definitely does not imply A and B are mutually exclusive.

If you say `either A or B`, then as far as my English allows me to say, I think it somewhat implies mutual exclusivity.

But I have also heard the phrase `either A or B or both`.

So... :) in English the meaning seems a bit fuzzy, at least for a non-native speaker.
It would be good a native speaker to chime in.

In my language in math proofs we say just `A or B` (we basically have no word for either),
and this phrase does not imply A and B are mutually exclusive.

Comment: thank you for your comment!